# JIRA 5 logo size issue

Tags: jira

In JIRA 5

```
Administration -> System -> User Interface -> Look And Feel
```

when I changing logo with image size 57x30px (width/height)

```
Text from page: "The height of the logo image will be constrained to a maximum of 30 px. 
Also, it is recommended to use an image with a 57 px width."
```

its displayed on jira page with size 187x40px (width/height) and looks very blurry. 
How can I fix this? (disable logo stretches)

Comment: Ask Atlassian folks themselves!

Comment: Thanks, I sent a support request.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in Jira 6.4 and confluence 5.8...

In JIRA, the image size you want (without scaling) will be 30px tall.  Any image height taller than 30 will be scaled to 30.  JIRA automatically puts padding on your image 5 top 5 bottom...for total of 40 pixels high.  JIRA will allow you to do an image wider than 57...it pushes the menu over..at least in the default theme.

In Confluence, for some reason the authors decided 5 pixels was not enough padding.  So, they added 3 more.  Top and bottom.  For a total of 16 pixels of padding.

Yes, the confluence tag line below the image upload says, "limit to 48 pixels tall", but this is a lie.  if you make it 48px tall, it will be scaled to 24 px tall.  Then the 16 pixels of padding is added for a total hight of 40px.

I will be checking on Stash/Bamboo in the future.